# How to solve vue 3 compatible packages problem?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to update my packages with npm.
I want to use vue 3 but there are some problems in these 3 packages:

- @vue/composition-api
- vue-class-component
- vue-property-decorator

I cannot install them.
For example this is the error output for vue-property-decorator:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: front@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.2.37
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.2.37" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"*" from vue-property-decorator@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm ERR!     vue-property-decorator@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-class-component@7.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-class-component
npm ERR!   peer vue-class-component@"*" from vue-property-decorator@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm ERR!     vue-property-decorator@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/ed/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ed/.npm/_logs/2022-07-13T10_36_11_427Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I use these packages with vue 3?

Comment: `@vue/composition-api` is for Vue 2, not needed in 3. Use the latest versions for vue-class-component, not stable one

Answer (score 0):

`vue-property-decorator` fully depends on `vue-class-components` (source: [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-property-decorator)), but `vue-class-components` has not been updated in the last 2 years.
I can't seem to find any post about a Vue 3 version, so I think it's just made for Vue 2. Your log says:

> peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-class-component@7.2.6

It's looking for the verision 2 of Vue, not the 3.
For `@vue/composition-api`, it's now an official API in Vue 3, why would you like to install the backport of Vue 2 in the Vue 3 version?